# Logging into Shopify using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm trying to post discount codes to a user's shop using the reverse engineering instructions shown here http://ma.rtin.so/reverse-engineering-shopify-private-apis (instructions are in PHP)

The first step is properly logging into the users account so I can grab information from the response. Am I doing this step correctly? I feel like I'm missing something to do with tokens, but its hard for me to understand the PHP code given in the instructions.

I am receiving a response without an error status code from the login function but I still don't know if this means I'm doing it correctly. Thanks for any help.

#### Node.js Discount Creation Controller (Please look at login function but included the whole thing in case)

```
use strict';
var request = require('request');
var cookie = require('cookie');

var USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.57 Safari/537.17';


var login = function(req, res, cb) {
    req.url = 'https://' + req.body.name + '.myshopify.com';
    var post_data = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        'redirect': '',
        'subdomain': req.body.name,
        'login': req.body.email,
        'password': req.body.pwd
    }

    var headers = {
        'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    };

    var url = req.url + '/admin/auth/login';
    request.post({ url: url, form: post_data, headers: headers }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) 'ERROR LOGGING IN';
        else {
            if (response.statusCode !== 200) throw 'ERROR LOGGING IN';
            console.log('Login response headers:', response.headers);
            var shopCookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];

            var j = request.jar();
            for (var i = 0; i < shopCookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = request.cookie(shopCookies[i]);
                j.setCookie(cookie, url);
            }
            req.cookie_string = j.getCookieString(url);
            if (cb !== undefined) cb(req, res);
        }
    });
};

var setCoupons = function(req, res) {
    var url = req.url + '/admin/discounts/new';
    var headers = {
        'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie': req.cookie_string
    };

    request.get({ url: url, headers: headers }, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) throw 'Problem setting coupons';
        var value = response.body.match(/name="authenticity_token" value=".*"/i)[0];
        var index = value.indexOf('value="');
        value = (value.substring(index + 7, value.length - 1));

        var count = parseInt(req.body.amount) + 1;
        var checkCount = count;
        var codes = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {
            var post_data = {
                utf8: '✓',
                authenticity_token: value,
                discount: {
                    code: req.body.code + "_" + i,
                    discount_type: req.body.discount_type,
                    value: parseInt(req.body.value),
                    applies_to_resource: '',
                    starts_at: '2016-04-10'
                },
                'unlimited-uses': '',
                discount_never_expires: ''
            }

            codes.push(post_data.discount);

            var url = req.url + '/admin/discounts';
            request.post({ url: url, form: post_data, headers: headers }, function(err, response, body) {
                checkCount--;
                if (checkCount < 2) {
                    res.send(codes);
                }
            });

        }


    });
};

export function create(req, res) {
    login(req, res, setCoupons);
}
```

Comment: Wait until the end of may 2016 and Shopify will release/open the Discounts API so you won't need to be doing reverse engineering.

Comment: @alexandresaiz, nevertheless I'm certain that Discounts API is only available for Shopify Plus customers.

Answer (score 0):

Discount codes are only available to Shopify Plus customers.
The API however is available now: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/discount

Also rather than using Shopify Plus it would be possible to create your own Discount code engine as an app and apply discounts to sales orders.